# Current sink - work in simulator, doesn't work in real

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, ltspice, wheatstone-bridge, current-sink

I've built current sink to drive wheatstone bridge. I've counted that I must reach current ~0.2mA to properly working whole measure system. Picture below present my current sink (I use MCP6001 op amp):
[image: current sink]

Before constructing whole device I've simulated it in LT-spice, and simulation looked good.

[image: Simulation]

Op amp is powered ofc. MCP6001 is low power amp with Rail-to-Rail Input/Output feature.
When I measure voltage on opamp output I've got zero volts... 
Is it possible to reach 0.2mA with this current sink based on MCP6001?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you powering your op-amp in the real world? I suspect that your device is not working because that op amp is not rail to rail...

Answer (score 1):

Options: -

- IC broken
- Power pins reversed or
- Input pins reversed
- Resistor values are not what you think
- 8k06 Resistor might be an inductor - check it out
- Maybe the output pin is not connected correctly (wrong pin)
- Output shorted to ground (solder splash/error)
- 1.6 volt input not connected to correct place
- 1.6 volt input shorted with solder splash
- Power supply broken or not switched on
- Oscilloscope/meter not connected properly
- Meter not reading DC but AC
- Oscilloscope/meter not working
- The laws of physics have finally decided not to work LOL

The last one is a really scary thought.